# How I can move a element in product description page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3

I want to move a small div which html is like in console

```
 <div class="feature-wrapper top-border">
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-5054e6c6502d114f"></script>
</div>
```

I want to include this div in

```
product.info.main
```

like in my xml  move is

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
```

so how I can include this div in product info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new PHTML file called `share.phtml` in `app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/share.phtml` and add your DIV inside it.

add below code in `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="share" template="product/view/share.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>.
```

then move your element inside `product.info.main`

```
<move element="share" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.addto" />
```

Comment: and how  you accessed that html ? I didnt get where and  how you include that div in phtml ?

Comment: Its a sharing script which you get online from sharethis site. So add that code inside phtml file and you are good to go

Comment: you have to add that div in share.phtml file and reference block inside XML file. check my update answer

Comment: basically my question is  how to add DIV inside xml. and you said 'and add your DIV inside it'   I dont know this step . can you tell about it please ?

Comment: Are you saying that I should include that html in phtml file as it is copy paste ?

Comment: DIV inside PHTML file.... call PHTML file inside XML file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66948/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-ephemeral).