# Product page custom container after image

Tags: category-products

I want to place a custom container inside the product wrapper on the category page. I have already tried

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="custom.description" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-description" befor="-">
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
```

But it does not work in my case. [image]

I just need to add a container between image and description. Actually I want to add a description in my custom container but add to cart button remains at that position.

Any help would be appreciated..!

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow the following step(s) to add a new container inside the reference container.**

> 1. Override catalog_category_view.xml and add the following code.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <container name="catnew" htmlTag="div" after="copyright">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="catnew-list" template="Module_Test::catnew.phtml" after="-"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

> 2. Add your the catnew.phtml file.

Comment: I dont want to add block actually. I want to move description from right bottom to center inside a new div.

Comment: Check that reference 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196832/how-i-can-move-a-element-in-product-description-page